# Reading files multi-data-type (c++)

Tags: c++, file, types

I want to read from one file that has several kinds of data-types. I utilize ifstream (C++ language) but it can't read strings.

In fact, I have written a code that has too many options and input parameters. Now, I want to read these parameters and (bool) options from an input file, then I can run my program by edition of input file and running makefile. I think I want something like this:

...
Number of Groups = 3
Name of Groups = David Jack Jill
...

Now, my code must allocate memory for "Groups" object. Group should have 3 member that their names are David, Jack and Jill.
Can anyone help me, please?
Thanks

Comment: This is straightforward. Can you post some code and tell us where you are having problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::ifstream` can certainly read strings. Have you remembered to include `<string>` though?